# Expression window font size

Tags: reporting-services

[alt text http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/3560/jerryt.jpg](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/3560/jerryt.jpg)

Does anyone know how to fix the issue which is displayed in the image. This is the expression designer window in Reporting Services 2008. It appears that the font size has been significantly reduced, but as of yet we haven't been able to find an option to enlarge the font to its default size.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What if you increased the window size by expanding it from the lower right corner?

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't alter the font size unfortunately

Comment: From the looks of it it looks like the text is scrolled up rather than shrunk. Is it always appearing that way?